# "href" attribute not updated correctly after a checkbox update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I use the latest version of jQueryMobile (1.3.2).

I have a checkbox with a label that contains a title and two paragraphs.
I want to be able to click on the title and to display a popup according to the state of the checkbox:
If the checkbox is checked, the popup 1 is displayed on the screen.
On the contrary, if the checkbox is not checked, the popup 2 is displayed.

So the link to the popup depends on the state of the checkbox.

Here is my code :

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu1">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Activate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu2">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Desactivate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<ul id="listOfObjects" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
 <li>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
   <a id="link1" href="#popupMenu1" data-rel="popup"> Object 1</a> 
  </fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="custom"/>  
 </li>

 <li>
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">        
   <a id="link2" href="#popupMenu1" data-rel="popup">Object 2</a>
  </fieldset>  
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="custom"/> 
 </li>
</ul>

<script>
 function myFunction1()
 {
  if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) 
   $("#link1").attr("href", "#popup2"); 
  else 
  $("#link1").attr("href", "#popup1");         
 }

 function myFunction2()
 {
  if ($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) 
   $("#link2").attr("href", "#popup2"); 
  else 
   $("#link2").attr("href", "#popup1");       
 }
</script>
```

However with this expression:

```
<a id="link1" href="#popupMenu1" data-rel="popup">Object 1</a>
```

or
    `<a id="link2" href="#popupMenu1" data-rel="popup">Object 2</a>`

the displayed popup is always the popup1, whatever the state of the checkbox.
So how to set the correct link?

Comment: Remove the hash on the id '<a id="**#link1**" href="#popup1" data-rel="popup">Object1</a>'

Comment: I tried without the "hash" but it does not work. The displayed popup is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have the id on the `<a>` as `#link1` it should just be `link1`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function myFunction()
{
    if ($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) 
        $("#link1").attr("href", "#popup2"); 
    else 
        $("#link1").attr("href", "#popup1");     
}
```

Comment: I replace my function by yours. I also replace "#link1" by "link1" (without hash) but the displayed popup is always the popup mentioned in the href, whatever the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cmxh7/1/)

i have update you code a little bit change you javascript function:

hope this helps.

Let me know!

**HTML:**

```
<a id="link1" href="#">Object1</a>

<input type="checkbox" value="you selected the checkbox" id="checkbox2">check me if you like</input>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var test = '';
$('#link1').click(function () {    
    test = $('input:checked').length ? $('input:checked').val() : '';
    alert(test);
});
```

Comment: I replace "#link1" by "link1" but the displayed popup is always the same, whatever the state of the checkbox.

Comment: I have seen you fiddle demo and I am trying to adapt you function to my code.

Comment: In your function, if I replace '' by popupMenu1, the displayed message is "[objectHTMLDivElement]".